# Unusual behaviour of stroke-width javafx line-charts

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am using a line-chart as a bar-chart (due to some reasons), and setting line(bar) stroke-width dynamically in px. But it seems that increasing line's stroke-width, increases its length too, which is not expected.

[Both are programmatically set to T1,10 and T2,30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX9mx.png)

This code is responsible for setting the line stroke-width dynamically based on number of items on x axis.

```
    private void setGreenBar(Node node, double barWidth){
        node.setStyle("-fx-stroke: greenyellow; -fx-stroke-width: " + barWidth + "px;");
    }

    private void setRedBar(Node node, double barWidth){
        node.setStyle("-fx-stroke: red; -fx-stroke-width: " + barWidth + "px;");
    }
```

Comment: Presumably this all depends what kind of `Node` you are passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it but I guess this is due to the stroke line cap. The default is SQUARE but in your case BUTT would be the one to go for.

```
-fx-stroke-line-cap: butt
```